# Reading a text file of student names and text scores and finding an average

Tags: java, arrays, file, text, average

Currently I have text file that stores student names and their test scores. The format of the file is last name, first name, and test score. Each value in the text file is separated but a space. So the file looks similar to this:

```
Smith John 85
Swan Emma 75
```

I've got the code running so that it prints all the data to the console, but what I can't get it to do is take all the test scores, add them up, and find the average and print the average to the console. As well as print any students' whose score is 10 less then the average.

Right now this is the code I'm using to read and print the information to the console.

```
public class ReadTXT 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{

{
    String txtFile = "/Users/Amanda/Desktop/Studentdata.txt";
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";
String txtSplitBy = " ";

    try {

    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(txtFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {


        String[] LastName= line.split(txtSplitBy);
                    String[] FirstName = line.split(txtSplitBy);
                    String[] TS = line.split(txtSplitBy);

        System.out.println("Last Name: " + LastName[0] 
                             + "\n" +"First Name: " + FirstName[1] + "\n" + 
                            "Test Score: " + TS [2] + "\n") ;

    {
        double average = sum / i;
    }
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Done");

   }

  }
  }
```

And this is the code I was trying to use to find the average.

```
 int i =Integer.parseInt ("TS");
double sum = 0.0;
for (int x = 0; x < i; sum += i++);
{
double average = sum / i;
}
```

I keep getting this exception, though:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "TS"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at ReadTXT.main(ReadTXT.java:35)
```

I am new to learning java but I am trying.

Comment: Please show us your complete exception message as it usually will tell you (and us) exactly what is wrong.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Are you kidding? It's `java.lang.NumberFormatException: "TS" is not a valid number.`

Comment: @tbodt: I post that not just for us, but for the OP, so that they'll seriously look at the stack trace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "TS"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at ReadTXT.main(ReadTXT.java:35)
Java Result: 1

Comment: I know that TS is not a valid number that's why I was trying to cast it to a number

Comment: @user2603112: thanks. Next time, post it as an edit to your original question since you can't format a comment. The exception does in fact tell you exactly what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code here:

```
String[] LastName= line.split(txtSplitBy);
String[] FirstName = line.split(txtSplitBy);
String[] TS = line.split(txtSplitBy);
```

is not really needed, as you are splitting the line several times to create 3 different String arrays, what you want to do is split the line once and then assign variables from the array indexs like this:

```
String[] splitLine = line.split(txtSplitBy);
String lastName = splitLine[0];  //first element of array
String firstName = splitLine[1]; //second element of array
String score = splitLine[2];     //third element of array
```

Then you can parse the score as a string, which will be a number not the literal String you are trying `"TS"` you want the variable name, so leave out the `"`

```
int i = Integer.parseInt (score);
```

Then for each iteration in your while loop add to a total and have a count then calculate your average that way. (or create a List of scores )Like:

```
int total = 0;
int count = 0;
List<Integer> allScores = new ArrayList<Integer>();
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
{
    String[] splitLine = line.split(txtSplitBy);
    String lastName = splitLine[0];  //first element of array
    String firstName = splitLine[1]; //second element of array
    String score = splitLine[2];     //third element of array

    System.out.println("Last Name: " + lastName 
                         + "\n" +"First Name: " + firstname + "\n" + 
                        "Test Score: " + score + "\n") ;

    int i = Integer.parseInt (score);
    total += i;
    count++;
    // Add to List
    allScores.add(i);
}
double average = total/count;
```

To loop a List

```
for( Integer i: allscores)
{
    // Do the appropriate code here
}
```

If you need the names also you should create a Class to hold firstName, lastName and score then add these to your list.

[See This Tutorial on Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: "score" is not a number.

Comment: Now how would I print scores that are 10 less then the average?

Comment: Instead of just totally in the loop you may want to create an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of Scores then loop that (see edit) If you need the names also I would suggest creating your own Object to hold Name and score

Comment: So would my ArrayList code look like this:
ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: then
scores.add(i); ?

Comment: great but, when I use scores.add(i); it says it can't find variable

Comment: I understand I have to load it with the test scores from the file I'm just unsure of what variable to use in the array to add them if that makes sense

Comment: What variable cant it find? When you adding the scores to the List make sure that is in the loop when you reading in the scores, as in my example.

Comment: Oh I see now I was coding it outside the loop. I see my mistake now.

Comment: Okay so when I add the for loop right after allScores.add(i); it says that variable i is already defined in the main method

Comment: if I change the variable i to another name like x for example would that effect my results?

Comment: You will not need the for loop inside the loop when adding the data to the list, put this outside the while loop, So the process is this. Read data and add to list (while loop), all the scores are in the list, so you can now loop the list as needed (for loop), as data is "loaded" into program. This is now getting off topic for this Question so I suggest you search for how to use lists, there are plenty of posts about this.

Answer (score 1):

Oops:

```
int i =Integer.parseInt ("TS");
```

This doesn't make sense. What number is "TS" supposed to represent?

---

Edit: you state:

> I know that TS is not a valid number that's why I was trying to cast it to a number

You can't "cast" letters to a number, again it makes no sense.

You need to read in the Strings in the file and then parse those Strings, not some letters you make up.

---

What your code should do is:

- read in each line in the file in a for loop
- inside this loop, split the String using String's `split(" ")` method.
- Use `Integer.parse(...)` to parse the 3rd item in the array returned.

---

> So would I use Integer.parse(String [] TS)?

No, this won't even compile since you're trying to pass a String array into a method that takes a String parameter.

Comment: TS stands for test score

Comment: then how do I get the string value stored in TS and use it as an integer so I can find the average?

Comment: @user2603112: You need to parse the data held in the file. "TS" is a String, it's not the file.

Comment: So would I use Integer.parse(String [] TS)?